# ZooKeeper Stat struct not changing

Tags: c, apache, struct, apache-zookeeper

Hello I am working in the C binding for ZooKeeper and when I call the zoo_exists() or the zoo_get() functions, the stat parameter should be updated according to the documentation. However when I run my code:

```
create("/mypath", "testnode"); 
//this creates a znode /mypath with data stored being "testnode".

char* buffer= malloc(1);
int buffer_len=1;
struct Stat s;
zoo_get(zh, "/mypath", 0, buffer, &buffer_len, &s);
```

The documentation states:
\param buffer_len is the size of the buffer pointed to by the buffer parameter. It'll be set to the actual data length upon return. If the data is NULL, length is -1.

\param stat if not NULL, will hold the value of stat for the path on return.

Am I doing something wrong? my stat struct s does not get changed. Nor does my buffer_len. After getting the updated stat struct s, I want to use the s.datalength to get the full data stored in the znode by using the line:

```
 char* newBuffer = malloc(s.datalength);
 buffer_len = s.datalength;
 zoo_get(zh, "/mypath",0, newBuffer, &buffer_len, NULL);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, but why are you allocating a buffer with length `1` byte? What advantage does that have over using a simple variable? What is the relevance of a buffer sizeof `1` when you are reading a `struct`? BTW I am not a zoo keeper.

Comment: The reason i chose buffer length as 1 was because I would update buffer length after zoo_get() is called as it is supposed to return me the actual data length upon return ( as long as the length isn't -1?)  and i would use the s.datalength element of the Stat struct to confirm the data length. I would then recall zoo_get() with the right buffer_length value.